# Issue with conversion from C# to VB Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I found a short working example to get contacts with Google Contacts Api here: http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/, but when I try to translate it to VB Net I have the following error:

> BC30652 a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis.Core, Version = 1.8.1.31685, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' containing the type 'IDataStore' is required. Add it to the project

This is the only part that gives me the error:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                 , scopes
                                                                                 , "test"
                                                                                 , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                 , new FileDataStore("test")).Result;
```

In VB Net I have:

```vb
Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .ClientSecret = clientSecret
        }, scopes, "test", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("test")).Result
```

The error appears from `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`. Can anybody help me with a correct translation?

Comment: Did you add the assembly reference?

Comment: When you saw the error, what did you do? Did you read it?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with a conversion problem. There is simply a DLL missing which you have to add in your assemblies. Maybe the topic should be renanamed.

Comment: etalon11 I already have google api core. Dave how can I add the reference? Sorry if my questions are too basic, I´m still learning

Comment: When I add Imports Google.Apis.Core It shows me highlighted in green and says: ...dont have any public member or cant find them...

Answer (score 2):

As it is specified [in your link](http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/), you should install it from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/), or directly using the [nuget visual studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).

**[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/)** will installs all the dependencies. In you case, it's **[Google Api Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Core/)**

In fact, this a nothing to do with C# to VB conversion. It's just a missing reference.

Comment: That´s the thing, I already have installed the google api core, I must resinstall it?

Comment: @user3822492 Yes. Something may have gone wrong, since the reference (with the mentioned version) is not viewed as present. It may comes from a mismatch between the version referenced and the one expected. You could check the way assemblies are versioned. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
*When I tried to uninstall Google.Apis.Core it shows me that I can´t uninstall because Google.Apis.Auth depends of it.
*When I tried to uninstall Google.Apis.Auth it shows me that I can´t uninstall because Google.Apis.DriveV2 depends of it.
*When I tried to uninstall Google.Apis.Drive.v2 I saw that was able an update for it, then I updated Google.Apis.Drive.v2 and then everything works!
I hope this post helps anyone that have this issue and thanks all for your help.